# Add To The Top in the DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

This My code For binding My DataList ,and every item in datalist have a different button , 
the items sorted correctly by date but the index for each item not sorted with it ,
ex:
when insert a new data in employees table the data shows correct(sorted by date),the last employee was insert into employee table shows in the first item and take the index 0.
I want to know how i can to make his index The Last Index in my old data + 1 ?

```
private void bind()
{
  da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employees order by insert_date desc", m_SqlConnection);
  DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
  da2.Fill(dataSet2, "det");
  DataList1.DataSource = dataSet2.Tables["det"];
  DataList1.DataBind();

}

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn =  (Button)e.Item.FindControl("button4");
    Button btn2 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("button1");
    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select insert_stat from insert_detail where user_id='" + int.Parse(Session["id"].ToString()) + "'", m_SqlConnection);
    DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
    da2.Fill(dataSet2, "chk");
        if (dataSet2.Tables["chk"].Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex]["insert_stat"].ToString() == "accept")
        {
            btn.Visible = true;
            btn2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (dataSet2.Tables["chk"].Rows[e.Item.ItemIndex]["insert_stat"].ToString() == "reject")
            {
                btn.Visible = false;
                btn2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a SQL problem than a `DataList` issue.

I recommend that you rewrite your SQL in the `bind()` method to do a JOIN on the `insert_detail` table to get the `accept` or `reject` value out of the table and into the bound data set for the data list. This serves two benefits:

1. It eliminates the database call in the `DataList1_ItemDataBound()` method, which if you have dozens or hundreds of rows, then that is dozens or hundreds less database calls.
2. It allows you to put the `insert_stat` value into a `HiddenField` control in your `DataList` and then check the value in the `DataList1_ItemDataBound` event, like this:

   ```
   HiddenField theHiddenField =  e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;

   // Make sure we found the control, because the as operator 
   // returns null for a failed cast
   if(theHiddenField != null)
   {
       if(theHiddenField.Value.ToLower() == "accept")
       {
           btn.Visible = true;
           btn2.Visible = true;
       }
       else
       {
           btn.Visible = false;
           btn2.Visible = false;
       }
   }
   ```